# Google Drive API request timeout in python httplib2

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, httplib2

I have been using a google project with `Google Drive API` to create and update files in google drive, everything was working fine till yesterday. My python script was running fine too, but since couple of hours I am getting the following error:

```
lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1136, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
socket.timeout: timed out
```

This is the function I am using to connect with `Google Drive API`:

```
def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None
```

It's connecting to the `Google Drive API` but whenever my code is trying to do any action like read or write to a file or folder it's getting the `socket.timeout: timed out`.
I have changed my credentials even created a new project in `google dev console` with fresh new credentials, re-authenticated the API with my google account to get a new token, but nothing seems to be working.
I have checked the package dependency too with `pip check` and it returns there is no broken dependency.

`# Edit 1:`

My code to read file from `Google Drive`:

```
def __read_file_from_drive():
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'
    API_NAME = 'drive'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
    file = 'my_file_id'
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fd=fh, request=request)
    
    done = False
    while not done:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print('File downloaded...')

    fh.seek(0)
    return fh.read().decode('ascii')
```

Code to save file to `Google Drive`:

```
def __save_file_to_drive():
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'
    API_NAME = 'drive'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

    __folder_id = 'my_folder_id'
    __files = ['my_files_list']
    __mime_type = 'text/csv'

    for __file in __files:
        file_meta = {
            'name': __file,
            'parents': [__folder_id]
        }

        media = MediaFileUpload('./{0}'.format(__file), mimetype=__mime_type)
        service.files().create(
            body=file_meta,
            media_body=media,
            fields='id'
        ).execute()
```

The current error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/PycharmProjects/project_name/google_drive_upload.py", line 75, in <module>
    returned = int(__read_file_from_drive())
  File "~/PycharmProjects/project_name/google_drive_upload.py", line 65, in __read_file_from_drive
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 746, in next_chunk
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 227, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 196, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1708, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1424, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1346, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "~/mambaforge/envs/project_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1136, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Can you show some example code that reads/writes? Along with the line the error appears?

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo I have updated the question with the code snippet and the full error.

Comment: The issue was solved automatically at one moment, now it's happening again, please if anyone can help...

Answer (score 0):

just leave a comment for someone came here.
i faced the same issue when i trying to access google drive api behind proxy, there didn't have a specification error message point you to proxy, so sometime it not easy to find the root cause.

if you already know it's a proxy issue, you can solve it quick and easy,
set proxy from your IDE or CMD as below.

```
export http_proxy=http://{IP}:{port} 
export https_proxy=http://{IP}:{port}
```